# How do I define a range as a variable to use as an argument of an excel worksheet function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the excel worksheet Forecast() function in my vba code. The Forecast() function requires two ranges as arguments. I want to use a changing range as the input to this function, so I can't define a static range as the input (e.g. B2:B10).

```
For i = 1 To DailySize
        n = i + 1
        ForecastHours(i) = Cells(n, 4).Value
        ProgramDays(i) = Cells(n, 1).Value
    Next i    
For i = Start To ForecastSize
        Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=Forecast(" & Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(i, 1) & ","ForecastHours","ProgramDays")"
    Next i
```

The first for loop defines two arrays, ForecastHours and ProgramDays, that change in size based upon the variable DailySize. I was wandering if I could make these two arrays ranges, so that they could be the inputs to the Forecast() function in the second for loop.

I get a syntax error right now for the second for loop, probably because I'm trying to use the arrays as inputs rather than ranges. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can we see how you define `DailySize`?

Comment: `"=Forecast(" & Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(i, 1) & "," & ForecastHours & "," & ProgramDays & ")"`

Comment: @MarkS. DailySize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(3)) - 1                                                   So basically it's counting the number objects in a column.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm getting a compile error: type mismatch when I try that, any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: show how you declare ForecastHours and ProgramDays as that is probably your type mismatch issue; Did you declare them as ranges or arrays?

Comment: @Sorceri They are declared as dynamic arrays. Dim ForecastHours() As Variant, ProgramDays() As Integer. Then they get ReDim based on the variable DailySize. I know the arrays are working, I used the MsgBox in the first for loop to display the value of each array through each index step. Now I'm trying to figure out if I can turn them into ranges to be called out in that forecast() function. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyler per Scott's Answer; That is why I asked you to post how you declared them.  They needed to be Ranges.  Also, Mark Scott's answer as correct since you state it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the loops and declare the variables as ranges and use their addresses:

```
Dim ProgramDays As Range
Dim ForecastHours As Range

Set ProgramDays = Range("A1:A" & DailySize)
Set ForecastHours = Range("D1:D" & DailySize)

Worksheets("Data Inputs").Range("E" & Start & ":E" & ForecastSize + Start - 1).Formula = _
    "=forecast(" & Worksheets("Data Inputs").Cells(Start, 1).Address(0, 0) & "," & ForecastHours.Address(1, 1) & "," & ProgramDays.Address(1, 1) & ")"
```

Comment: @Tyler please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.